# Automatic JS, CSS Versioning to Update Browser Cache when Files are Changed in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

When you update JavaScript or CSS files that are already cached in users' browsers, most likely many users won’t get that for some time because of the caching at the browser or intermediate proxy(s). You need some way to force browser and proxy(s) to download the latest files. There’s no way to do that effectively across all browsers and proxies from the webserver by manipulating cache headers unless you change the file name or you change the URL of the files by introducing some unique query string so that browsers/proxies interpret them as new files. Most web developers use the query string approach and use a version suffix to send the new file to the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/TestScript.js" ></script>
<link href="Styles/Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

get converted to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js?v=20100319021342" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/TestScript.js?v=20110522074353" ></script>
<link href="Styles/Stylesheet.css?v=20110522074829" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I want any JS, CSS or Image Versioning to Update Browser Cache when Files are Changed.  How else can this be done?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you just described?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.madskristensen.net/blog/cache-busting-in-aspnet/).

Comment: thankyou wazz you solve my problem

Comment: in asp.net core you can user the tag-helper asp-append-version="true"
<script src="..." asp-append-version="true"></script>